# How Whatsapp shows link previews despite E2E encryption?

Tags: encryption, whatsapp, end-to-end-encryption

Someone sends me a link. Whatsapp shows its preview. How can they do that despite being E2E encrypted?

Comment: The link gets decrypted at some point of time (that's why you're able to view it). And maybe it's not WhatsApp that actually "shows" you the preview, maybe WhatsApp just gives the link to the OS and asks the OS to give you a preview.

Comment: What has the preview to do with E2E encryption? WhatsApp can locally create a preview, save it as image or similar and then send this image with E2E encrypted, similar to how user provided images or text messages are send.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the WhatsApp server sends the preview and not your local client.

Comment: @pri if OS gets the link from Whatsapp then OS has the info that this user is viewing this link?

Someone from my circle told that he got a link from her mom about a clothing item. Just after that she saw google ads. showing that ad to her on her phone!

Comment: pri, Steffen & schroeder. Just a newbie trying to learn ho privacy is ensured. Please refer to some good resource if you can.

The keyboard from google, etc. has all the what is being typed. Our passwords, CC details. Lets assume Google is a well known, law abiding citizen, but there are tones of 3rd party keyboards, launchers and apps on playstore which are used in other apps, like plugins. Does OS make sure that these apps don't leak user data to their servers? Or there is only law that stops them to do so? Interested in tech stuff. Thanks

Comment: You have to trust the OS.

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp client makes http request to the site as the sender types in, in order to fetch site meta properties.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Information Security Stack Exchange">
<meta property="og:description" content="Q&A by infosec enthusiasts">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/security/Img/logo.svg?v=f9d04c44487b">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://security.stackexchange.com">
```

Link preview requires sender to be online and the message is yet to be sent. WhatsApp client makes http request for any text that matches with the regular expression of the URL.

Once metadata is retrieved, it is sent as message. The problem with this design is that if there's a query string in a URL, WhatsApp client will not escape it and put it in a GET request as parameter. This leaks the next immediate word in the typed message if you forget to put space between the URL and text while typing the message.

Comment: WOW. This data can be sniffed. Will try today. Thanks. Plus do check the comments in question.

Answer (score 0):

Last I knew they used GET requests, this does pose some issues as it leaks IP, device info and WhatsApp version. The chats themselves are encrypted though. This information is a little outdated but I am not aware of it changing, although I can't rule out WhatsApp has updated its security since then.

See https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/15/should-whatsapp-let-you-disable-url-previews/ for more information

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 possible ways to implement link previews with E2E:

1. the sending client fetches the URL directly and generates the preview that is then sent encrypted in the message
2. the client uses the service servers to retrieve the URL

WhatsApp uses the first option:

- this means the website will know your device IP, and possibly some other metainformation about your device
- if the URL is malicious your device might get compromised (although, given the goal is to simply generate a preview, the settings for the component visiting the URL should be safer than the already safe default browser settings)
- there is no chance for the servers to know any part of your conversation

Signal uses the second option... basically Signal servers act as proxies:

- the Signal client establishes a connection to the site using the servers as proxies
- in this way the website does not know your IP or other device metadata, only the one from Signal servers
- obviously Signal servers do know a bit of information about the website you are connecting to, however the proxy can be implemented in a way that does not disclose the actual URL visited by the Signal client.

More information here:  https://community.signalusers.org/t/link-preview-when-pasting-or-typing-links/2370/65

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this behavior of whatsapp when i was typing in a url on my own website.  My site does not have property="og: ...  meta data, only the decription string.  Yes it accesses or probes the server for every click.  It bevaves like key logger.

Yes, by adding the additional header info, WhatsApp sent urks arr richer and the receivers get additional ifo before they open.

However, WhatsApp does not have to do this way at all just for accomplishing the above. The alternate simple way is for WhatsApp to wait till the url typing is completed with a white space  BEFORE it probes.  Since that would reduce the overall probing load on the WhatsApp servers, and the target servers by several fold.

So I inclined to think WhatsApp is doing this key logging like beviour and probing for everying, not just urls, and possibly snooping in on everything before they end to end encrpt and send the mdg.  Yes this strong suspicious allegation.  Why else would they not use the simpler method I suggested above?

When I saw this behavior, I thought it was a key logger vurus in my whatsapp or the Gboard I was usin on my Android 10 phone.